# Play several media together with omxplayer

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to open several videos together(in the same time) on my raspberry PI, with the player omxplayer.

My final goal is to see how much stream can I show in one screen (1920x1080)

I tryed to use the omxplayer's option --win "x1 y1 x2 y2" to determine the coordinates where the 2 video are supposed to be played (one in top left corner, the other in bottom left), but when I launch them (even in differents consols), only the first one is played. The second video started when the first is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution: it seems like olds versions of omxplayer aren't able to allow this functionnality. So i just install the last version ( Version   : 9b0793f [master] ), and everything's working. I could play 4 videos in the same time on the same screen, but not more (cpu around 95-99%, even if overclocked to turbo (1ghz)